# Rails fixtures entries can be invalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Hunt` model where I validate it with

`validates :title,:clue, :user_id,presence: true`

My understanding of `fixtures` is that , the entries would be saved to the database so it needs to be `valid`. But in my fixtures , I have

```
one:
  title: MyString
  user: raj
```

which is not `valid`. But it works without any errors.

If it is saved to the database, shouldnt it fail when it validates? Or is this the intended behaiour and validations are not run?

Answer (score 0):

The data in fixtures does not have to pass model validation before it is loaded into database.

As a side note, fixtures are generally considered as not the best
way of testing. A better, commonly used alternative for build-in are factories (I recommend [Factory Bot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Bot_(Rails_Testing))).

I advise to ignore fixtures from the beginning and go straight to factories.

Comment: This is not the problem of fixtures. You can validate your record with `assert @user.valid?` along with other tests if you want.